# Quick effects smoke simulation not rendering in viewport together with other animations

Tags: animation, 3d-view, smoke-simulation

I'm relatively new to blender, and today I started exploring smoke simulations. I encountered a weird issue when creating a smoke simulation inside of an animated scene, there is simply no proper simulation playback in the viewport and instead it makes the whole domain grey with smoke. Wouldn't want to keep rendering it to make edits, that would take forever.

My main idea was to give the little guy a smoking head as he is walking inside.
[image: Scene setup]

In a fresh blender file, the quick smoke effect works as expected and without issues, without baking first. I tried appending the walking body mesh and armature into a new blender file, and upon adding a quick smoke simulation, the same thing happened, it's all weird and glitchy.

I tried changing from "replay" to "all" in the cache settings, baking it, but still no luck, it just won't play together with other animations in the viewport.

The only way I can preview the smoke animations is through rendering them first and previewing in the animation viewer. But another problem arises when I try to move the smoke domain or resize it - blender crashes.

[image: Weird box glitch]

Thank you for your time!

My system specs:
i9-119000k
RTX 3090
Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: How much experience do you have in smoke simulations? No offense, but first of all it sounds as if you haven't baked your simulation yet. The smoke simulation uses **a lot** of resources, and (depending on the resolution of course) without baking it will probably never play proper in the viewport. Even with baking, high resolution smoke simulations won't play very well. I would recommend this tutorial by Polyfjord for a beginner's guide to smoke simulations and how to preview the resulting animation: [Creating a fireball in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyIJQHlFQs0)

Comment: That's the exact tutorial I followed. As I already mentioned in my post, I just started today, and I already tried baking it and it still would not play.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is unfortunately no way to preview quick smoke simulation in the viewport when there are other simulations. The only way is to use mp4 animation previews.

The issue with the smoke domain refusing to move/be resized without crashing blender seems to be because I was not at frame 0 and needed to press "Free Bake".